# Возникла проблема при асинхронном появлении элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Я использую цикл for для появления элементов. По идее они должны отображаться асинхронно (спустя 1.5 секунды должен появляться каждый новый элемент), но к сожалению проходит 1.5 секунды и появляются сразу все элементы, которые должны отобразиться.

P.S. Использую JQuery

```
var amount = [];
/*numbers-это число, которое передается из input*/
for (var i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
  amount[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  setTimeout(createBubbleElement, 2500, '.array', i);
}

function createBubbleElement(parent, identifier) {
  $(parent).append('<div class="ball bubble"><span class="number ' + identifier + '"></span></div>')
}
```

Comment: дак, конечно,  вы в цикле задаете n-ное числое таймаутов. и все они через этот заданный таймаут выполнятся. Созайте таймер, при срабатывании добавляйте элемент. Когда будет создано нужное количество - удалите таймер.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я так понял, нужно использовать setInterval(). Поставил его после цикла. Но как высчитать нужное количество, если я уже не использую цикл?

Comment: вам не нужен цикл. таймер вам его как раз и заменит. нужное количество очевидно увеличивать при срабатывании функции в интервале.

Comment: Получается, нужно увеличивать параметр identifier. Но вот чего я не пойму, увеличивая его, он же увеличивается только внутри функции. И как в последующем мне его сравнивать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените цикл использованием `setInverval`. Через нужное число итераций уберите таймер.

Условно все это выглядит примерно так:

```js
var count = 10;
var idx = 0;

var ih = setInterval(function(){
     var amount =   Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

     $('<div class="ball bubble"><span class="number"></span></div>')
         .data('amount', amount)
         .data('idx', idx)  //attr('data-idx', idx) если потребуется поиск по атрибуту
         .find('.number').text(idx + '/' + amount).end()
         .appendTo('body');

     if(++idx == count){
          clearInterval(ih);
     }
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```